# UK visa for a baby which type is better? And how much required

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, dependent-visa

My husband is studying in the UK till next September. He has a valid Tier 4 visa, and I have a valid Tier 4 dependent visa, both valid till January. 
We had a baby there, then I had to leave with the baby to have an operation in my home country. 
Now I want to re-join my husband, and take my baby with me.

My baby has a British birth certificate, but of course no citizenship. 
Which kind of visa would have more chance of acceptance for our baby? A Tier 4 dependent visa? We will go in July, and the studies end in September. Would my husband still have the right to ask for dependents?
Or would it be better to apply for a visitor visa? How much money should we show that we have for the baby's stay in case we apply for visitor visa for 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

I would apply for the visitor visa, on the basis that you can demonstrate that the visit is for less than six months. A dependent visa is intended for stays over six months, and would normally be the applicable choice, assuming that you are eligible based on your husband's course of study.

However in this scenario it seems that a trip from July to September (three months) is properly characterised as a 'visit'.

Of course as a visitor you must properly demonstrate ties to your home country and an intention to return, as there may be a assumption that with all three of you in the country, you will overstay.

Info at http://www.ukcisa.org.uk/Information--Advice/Visas-and-Immigration/Dependants